# MS Access -- choose field based on cell contents

Tags: ms-access-2016

Other than building an IIF statement for an Access field in a query, how can I use the cell contents to determine what field I pull data from?

I have a date field and depending on the date I would like to pull data from a  different fields (ie: if the date is 1/1/2018 I want to pull from FieldA, if the date is 2/1/2018, I want to pull from FieldB.  In the past, I have done that with a long IIF statement, but I wanted to know if there was a more elegant/simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd consider [Switch function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379?ocmsassetID=HA001228918&CorrelationId=d601185b-0235-4cd6-9b57-2ac7ef3b4435&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) a bit more elegant.

Eg.

```
SELECT
Switch(
    date < 'xxx', FieldA,
    date >= 'xxx', FieldB
    ) AS field
FROM table;
```